# Jmeter shows error after request takes more than 15 seconds to execute

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have been trying to run a jmeter test, but everytime if some requests take more than 15 seconds to execute than it shows it as an error and says "Target sever failed to respond". I have already set all the timeout in apache2, mySQL and php config to very high.
For the jmeter file, the connection timeout is 30 seconds and Response timeout is set to 120 seconds.
You can check in the image that all the errors are after 15 seconds and they are random as well.

[image]

Comment: Include the image here instead of posting it as a link for better answers

Comment: @Jeffin It's a new account so they won't allow me to post image till I reach 10 points limit. :(

Comment: Oh my bad , changed it

Comment: wow @Jeffin.. thanks man.!

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable KeepAlive in HTTP Request.

If you need to have KeepAlive enabled, try this

1. In `jmeter.properties` file uncomment this line `hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters` and change this line `httpclient4.retrycount=2`
2. In `hc. parameters` file uncomment this line and set number of miliseconds to greater value(e.g. 30s) `http.socket.timeout$Integer=30000`

Take care! This strategy is very aggresive to server

Comment: wow.. uncommenting the http.socket.timeout$Integer=30000 actually worked. At least not receiving error on 15 seconds, the time limit is high now..

Comment: I thought it did resolve the issue but it did not actually. I am still getting the same result and it shows error and max time around 15 seconds.